# Define all points in the affine integral lattice.

Tags: group-theory, integer-lattices

Define all points in the affine integral lattice $\mathcal{L}=\{(x,y,z,t) : x+y+z+t=5$ and $x-z \equiv 0$ (mod $12$)$\} \subset \mathbb{Z}^4$.

This is a question from a practice exam I have with no solutions.  I'm not certain what to do but this is what I have so far.  It could be completely wrong so take it with a pinch of salt.  I will be using an algorithm that our lecturer described in one of our lectures.

First define $H =\{(x,y,z,t) : x+y+z+t=0$ and $x-z \equiv 0$ (mod $12$)$\}$.

We will be considering $\pi_i:\mathbb{Z}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

Consider $\pi_4:\mathbb{Z}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$.

Then ker($\pi_4$) we choose a vector satisfying the conditions stated in $H$.  i.e. $(1,9,1,1) \in H$

Next we consider ker($\pi_4)\cap H=\{(x,y,z,0) : x+y+z=0$ and $x-z \equiv 0$ (mod $12$)$\}$.

This time I choose the vector $(1,10,1,0) \in$ ker($\pi_4)\cap H$.

I then go to do this again and find that the next two vectors must be $0$, as in the first case I consider $\{(x,y,0,0) : x+y=0$ and $x \equiv 0$ (mod $12$)$\}$ so $x$ must be zero and hence so must $y$, and similarly for the next case.

So I therefore think that I have a basis for $H$, i.e.

$$
H= \begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 9 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \mathbb{Z}
+
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 10 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \mathbb{Z}
$$

And then to rewrite to include the $5$ I write:
$$
\mathcal{L}= \begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
 5 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+ 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 9 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \mathbb{Z}
+
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 10 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \mathbb{Z}
$$

So basically my question is: have I answered the question and/or have I found a basis for $\mathcal{L}$?

EDIT: I edited the

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
 5 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

from a 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 5 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so that it wouldn't effect the $x-z$.

Answer (score 1):

Your second vector, 
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
   1 \\
   10 \\
   1 \\
   0
\end{bmatrix},
$$
is not a member of $H$.

Specifically, $$1+10+1 = 12 \ne 0.$$ Notice that the first equality is not modulo 12.

This means that your basis is not a basis for $H$.

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I made a mistake in my answer.

The third and fourth vector should respectively be defined as:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
12 \\
-12 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} $ and $
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

Therefore the basis is as follows:

$$
\mathcal{L}= \begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
 5 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
+ 
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 9 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \cdot \mathbb{Z}
+
 \begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 10 \\
 1 \\
 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \mathbb{Z}
+
 \begin{bmatrix}
 12 \\
 -12 \\
 0 \\
 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}\cdot \mathbb{Z}
$$